# Lifetime of a class returned as const reference

Tags: c++, lvalue

If I try to return a string literal from a function, I can make these two versions:

```
std::string get_val()
{
    return "1234";
}

const std::string & get_ref()
{
    return "1234";
}
```

However, what confuses me is that I thought you need to have a long-lived object, in order to have an lvalue reference (I am reading `const std::string &` as an lvalue reference, perhaps I am mistaken).

Why does this work? Where does `"1234"` live after I return from the function?

Comment: I don't think it works, in fact GCC throws a warning for that code and if you try to call get_ref() it crashes https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/90U

Comment: Second version of `get_ref()` is invalid. It may seem to work but it is still invalid to return a reference to a local object.

Comment: What compiler and warning level (or lack thereof) are you using, where this isn't diagnosed?

Comment: Oh crap, it makes sense then. The problem is that `std::string & get_ref()` was a compiler error, but adding `const` passed the build and I didn't notice the warning. I am using gcc with -Wextra, but I just got confused and posted here too soon. Sorry everyone!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/72178.

Comment: It may "work" until something has overwritten the carcass of a `std::string` that is decomposing where the temporary string used to be. Appearing to work is the most devious form of undefined behaviour.

Comment: XD that's a nice way to describe it @molbdnilo, and coming from C it's completely logical. But I am just beginning C++ and reading about lvalue refs, rvalue refs and move/copy semantics is a rollercoaster of aha! and wtf? moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second implementation is not valid.

Actually `return "1234"` creates a temporary(rvalue) string object(as if it was `return std::string("1234")`) which resides on the stack, and as soon as it returns the returned reference becomes a dangling reference as it was on the stack memory.

Recent compilers would make a warning like:

https://godbolt.org/z/hWM76n

```
<source>: In function 'const string& get_ref()':
<source>:5:12: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    5 |     return "1234";
      |            ^~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string get_val()
{
    return "1234";
}
```

In this case an object of string type is created and then the move constructor(mostly will say a copy but due to compiler optimization move is more likely to be called ) is called to store the value in the destined variable

```
const std::string & get_ref()
{
    return "1234";
}
```

In this here you are returning a refrence to a temporary local object, so when the constructor of string done constructing the string object with "1234" and the return is called the object is destroyed after that as the object created was temporary with the local scope. It should throw an error to you